# How to change the name or alias a python module

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using a python app, via django, that requires Pillow, and I have installed it via pip. However, when the framework loads it complains that Pillow is not installed. I can verify this when trying `import pillow` fails.

If I look at the directory that contains the python modules I see there is no "pillow", but there is "PIL". I understand that pillow is a fork of PIL, and I can `import PIL` (PIL appears in a list of modules within python >>> help() >>> modules).

Without touching the framework, is there a way to convince the app/django that PIL == pillow. I tried `import PIL as pillow` in a settings file, but that didn't solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question:

```
>>> import PIL as pillow
>>> pillow
<module 'PIL' from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py'>
```

Note that you need to add the import line in the module you plan to use it.

Comment: I think this won't work, as the problem is that something in the framework, or another module is using `import pillow`. Using `import PIL as pillow` and then `import pillow` causes the same error as if you just `import pillow`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put this in your startup code it would work.

```py
import sys
import PIL
sys.modules["pillow"] = PIL
```

Comment: This works, in the sense that after your code `import pillow` does not fail. But I cannot find a place to put it in the code I have so that the framework does not fail when it tests for the presence of `pillow`. So, a good answer, but can't make it work for me.